# Ubuntu - enable dhcp client on all interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dhcp

I build a VM image for different visualiser types, and I would like it to use dhcp on all available network interfaces (wired only).

I'm using Ubuntu server.

Pre-creating `/etc/network/interfaces` is not an option since I can't predict the number of network interfaces, nor their names.

I tried to use network-manager, it works fine (you just need to install it and it will try to connect via any network interface, using DHCP), but will bring 200MB of dependencies on a headless Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [dhcpcd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/dhcpcd5.8.html); depending on Ubuntu version, it *may* be called *dhcpcd5*. It installs as a convenient *systemd* service, and by default it listens on **all** interfaces. In fact, it has a *-z* option to *limit* the interfaces it listens on, but if you do not use the option you get the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in this posting https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164660/why-are-post-up-commands-in-etc-network-interfaces-ran-multiple-times-at-boot

Add a script to /etc/network/if-up.d which  uses $IFACE to run dhclient the whenever an interface (any interface) comes up?

I'm working on a similar issue right now if anyone has a better idea I'll vote for theirs :^)